# Laravel 5 app timezone change dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5, I face the problem to change timezone dynamically. I show my code below,

**Function from provider**

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        Config::set('app.timezone',  'Australia/Sydney');
    }
}
```

**My controller**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon;
use Config;

class EmployeesAttendanceController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
      $time = Carbon\Carbon::now();
      echo $time;
    }

}
```

When I add straight from `config/app.php` timezone work fine; for example `'timezone' => 'UTC'` to `'timezone' => 'Australia/Sydney'`, but when I set it from the provider then timezone doesn't work.

Comment: Try in the `boot()` method instead and also try `date_default_timezone_set()` function.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change your time zone from `config/app.php` you can handle this **dynamically**  with the help of PHP `DateTime` class and  **setTimezone**  function.

like this:-

```
$time = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i'), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$time->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
$time = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $time;
```

**Note**:- Make sure that `'timezone' => 'UTC'` in `config/app.php` file.